# Does ACCESS 10 use VB 6 or VB.Net

Tags: ms-access, vba

Environment = Windows 7, Office 10, SQL Server.

I need to print to an Ithaca 280 serial Printer form an ACCESS button control, and have code examples from the manufacturer that are only a bit helpful.  One example is for VB 6 the other is for vb.net. First I need to know which I am dealing with In ACCESS.

Comment: I do wonder why you refuse to accept a single answer to any of your multiple questions. It is actually frustrating for people who are helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither - it's VBA. But that's much closer to VB6 than to VB.Net. So work with the VB6 sample.